# Group Based Licensing in Azure AD - Get Direct and Inherited Licences AzureAD module

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Group Based Licensing has now been made GA, however it appears as though all the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/licensing-ps-examples) is based around using [MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0) module. In Microsoft's own words:

> Customers are encouraged to use the newer Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module instead of this module.

I would like to use the newer AzureAD module to report on the way in which a user has been licensed - either inherited (from a Group) or direct. `Get-AzureADUser` doesn't appear to return any information that allows identification of such, nor does `Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail`.

In the [beta schema for an Azure AD user account](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/user) (inherited from directoryObject) this has a `licenseAssignmentState` property of type `licenseAssignmentState collection`, which contains an `assignedByGroup` property that would help solve this issue. This property is missing from the v1.0. API.

Is it possible to make the AzureAD module use the Beta API at all? Or, is there an estimate of when additional properties will make it over to the 'GA' API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you still need to use the MSOnline (v1) module for this.

The AzureAD (v2) module currently uses the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) for most cmdlets (including `Get-AzureADUser` and `Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail`), not the Microsoft Graph API.

At the time of this writing, there is no published estimate for when the newer cmdlet module will expose these details.